# What are the return/exit codes for resize2fs?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a script to resize my backup image files for my banana pi.

I notice when I `man resize2fs`, that the man page doesn't contain a section for return/exit codes.  I don't think I've come across a man page that didn't have this section.

My google searching has not be helpful at all.  Does anybody have any idea what the available return/exit codes are for resize2fs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking the source [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/fs/ext2/e2fsprogs.git/tree/resize). It looks like the only available exit codes are `ENOMEM (12)`, `1` and `0`. On a `malloc()` fail, on other errors, and on success, respectively.

Comment: Ty, I don't know why checking the source code was such a foreign idea to me.